# Customized debug/flask Flask python

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, web-applications, flask-login

I have created an webapp.The home page consists of a login form and upon login it will redirect to "host_address/security_portal". And once I logout I tried accessing this security_portal page it says

> could not build url for endpoint 'login'. Did you mean 'logout' instead

what I want is a customized error page instead of this debug page.

```py
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def home():
    form = LoginForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
    # Grab the user from our User Models table
        user = User.query.filter_by(email=form.email.data.lower()).first()
        if user==None:
            flash('The E-mail is not registered! Kindly register and login')
            return redirect(url_for('home'))
        
        if user.check_password(form.password.data) and user is not None:
            #Log in the user

            login_user(user)
            next = request.args.get('next')
            #check if user trying to access page that needs login without signing in#
            if next == None or not next[0]=='/':
                next = url_for('security')
            return redirect(next)
        else:
            flash("Incorrect Password!")
        
    return render_template('home.html',form=form)
@app.route('/SecurityPage')
@login_required
def security():
    return render_template('SecurityPage.html',username=(current_user.email.split('@'))[0].split('.')[0].capitalize())
```

Comment: Please add some code so we can better understand what might go wrong :)

Comment: Yeah I just added it here. Thanks for pointing it out @KnijnOps